# C++ 11 STL Lists = and != op not defined

Tags: c++, list, stl

I am trying to use C++ list ADT, but I can't seem to make the iterator or call to work right. I don't know how to initialize a new list from an array, and I keep getting the error that = and != operators are not defined for iterator. This code IS based on a friends homework (I was trying to show him he could improve his code by using lists). I've cut out all the logic but the variable declarations and the portion of code that throws error.

```
#include <list>

using namespace std;

const static char *dias[] = {"Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado"};

//Don't know how to initialize list from array
const static list<char *> DIAS (7);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    list<char *>::iterator iter;

        //ERROR HERE. Says = and != operator not defined for iterator iter.            
    for(iter = DIAS.begin(); iter != DIAS.end(); ++iter){
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I based my code on the example code and documentation found at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/list/

Comment: Prefer [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) over that other site.

Comment: `const` containers have no `iterator`s, just `const_iterator`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your list is `const`, so you need a `const_iterator`:

```
list<char *>::const_iterator iter;
```

In C++11, you could have avoided this problem with a simple modification to your code:

```
for(auto iter = DIAS.begin(), end = DIAS.end(); iter != end; ++iter){ ... }
```

As for the list initialization, C++11 allows you to do this:

```
static const std::list<const char*> DIAS{"Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", 
                                         "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sabado"};
```

Note that the type should be `const char*`, since the elements point to string literals.

Comment: I am using VS Express for Windows Desktop IDE with the vc++ compiler and when using the above form for initialization it outputs the following error:

    `Error 1 error C2470: 'DIAS' : looks like a function definition,    but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body    c:\users\nelson\documents\visual studio    2012\projects\fakeproject\fakeproject\source.cpp 20 1 FakeProject`

Comment: @user1856664 you did say C++11 though. This is valid C++11.

Comment: Visual studio does not support initialization lists

Comment: @AK4749, At least not in the library. The compiler does.

Comment: Hm, well if other say it works it must work. I guess either Express doesn't support C++11 or I have to set it to compile to c++11 manually.

Comment: So it seems in trying to show my friend an alternative to his code I unknowingly stepped on a landmine? Lucky for him he uses Zinjai which is a front-end for gcc, so it should theoretically work even if it doesn't for me in VS Express.

Comment: @user1856664 sorry, I don't use VS so I am immune from its limitations (I have to deal with other compilers' limitations though.)

Comment: @user1856664 yes, GCC 4.8.1 is expected to be the first fully-compliant (major features) C++11 compiler

Comment: @chris So if I point vc++ to GCC's runtime library it should work? interesting.

Comment: I'd give you guys a Nobel Peace Prize if I could, but for now I'll just accept the answer. Sorry for not RTFM, I don't program in C++, but I thought that this would be easy enough that I could get away with not knowing the language.

Comment: @user1856664 you can always try another compiler. See [this demo with g++](http://ideone.com/OdKrxi).

Comment: @AK4749, Are you sure? Clang should be fully-conforming this Summer. Actually I just saw the post. I wonder which will come out first. Meanwhile, `void foo() &;` is valid syntax? Where was I when this happened?